# Anyone heard of EnableBranchCacheHashGeneration?

Tags: powershell

I am going through some exam prep for the 70-489 exam and ran across a question that has EnableBranchCacheHashGeneration as a possible answer.  I cannot find anywhere online where this is property is mentioned.  Is this a made up property to through you off the scent, or has someone actually used this?  It would be used for caching files using a PowerShell command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Over-simplified**

> `Branch­Cache` will use a por­tion (5% default) of a client com­put­ers hard drive to store requested files (or chunks of files). So, sec­ond requests for the same file will use this locally cached copy. That elim­i­nates the need to re-download this large file over the WAN.

Don't know much about it but I found it on below article.

[SharePoint and BranchCache](http://www.wahidsaleemi.com/2010/06/sharepoint-and-branchcache/)

Comment: Just clarified that part as quoted from the link